# Consider the metric space of infinite sequences of 0s and 1s under this metric.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, compactness

For $x, y ∈ \{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$, define $d(x, y) = 2^{-n}$ where $n$ is the first position where the sequences $x$ and $y$ are different.

1. Show that ($\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}, d$) is compact.
2. Show that the set P of periodic elements (sequences where there exist $m>0$ such that $x_i = x_{m+i}$ for all $i$) is countable and dense.

**What I tried**

For part 1, I have been trying to use the fact that a set is compact if every sequence has a convergent subsequence. But I keep confusing myself with the fact that the elements are sequences and then if I’m supposed to take sequences of those sequences.

For part 2, I’m really not sure where to start. With regards to countability, my initial thought is that if an element is periodic then there is a finite number of elements that get repeated. And since there are only 2 possible options for any given entry, we are arranging a finite number of elements in finite ways? But I am not sure about density.

Comment: @DanRust For part 1, I have been trying to use the fact that  a set is compact if every sequence has a convergent subsequence. But I keep confusing myself with the fact that the elements are sequences and then if I’m supposed to take sequences of those sequences.

Comment: @DanRust For part 2, I’m really not sure where to start. With regards to countability, my initial thought is that if an element is periodic then there is a finite number of elements that get repeated. And since there are only 2 possible options for any given entry, we are arranging a finite number of elements in finite ways? But I am not sure about density.

Comment: Here are some hints: For 1, take your sequence (of sequences) and split it into two subsets, those which start with 0 and those which start with 1. One of those two subsets (or both) is infinite, say those starting with 1. Split those into ones starting with 10 and ones starting with 11. Keep the subset that's infinite. Keep going... end up with a sequence of bits to which a subsequence converges.

Comment: For 2, a periodic element is determined by the finite string of bits that repeats; show there are only countably many finite strings of bits (since there are only finitely many of length $k$ for each $k$). For density, given arbitrary sequence $x$, find a periodic sequence that agrees with the first $n$ bits of $x$, how close is that to $x$?

Comment: So what is $N$ standing for? I thought it refers to binary sequences of length $N$....

Comment: @MostafaAyaz it’s actually $\mathbb{N}$, this is the notation from my textbook.

Comment: Thank you and sorry if I wasn't familiar to this convention....

Comment: @Ned I don’t understand how that works. How does continually taking infinite subsets create a sequence to which a subsequence (of what?) converges?

Comment: see the answer below, its exactly what I described.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that the metric defined on the set is really so. For showing compactness take any arbitrary sequence of sequences say $\lbrace a_n\rbrace$. Clearly there are infinitely many sequences of $\lbrace a_n\rbrace$ with 1st bit being either $0$ or $1$. If there are finitely such sequences that results the whole $\lbrace a_n\rbrace$ to have finite terms which is a contradiction. Take one of such sequences say $a_{n_1}$. Now among those subsequences with 1st bit $1$ or $0$ choose those of 2nd bit being $1$ or $0$ (whose there are infinitely many of them there). There are such infinite sequences with the same argument. So far we have found infinitely many sequence with 1st 2 bits being at least either $00,01,10,11$. Take one of those sequences and name it $a_{n_2}$. Keep on this procedure and make $\lbrace a_{n_k}\rbrace$ as a sunsequence of $\lbrace a_n\rbrace$. This subsequence clearly converges to the same sequence we were fixing each bit every time. So the metric space is compact.

For showing countability of $P$, the set of periodic sequences, let's count them manually. Please note that there are finitely many periodic sequences corresponding to each $m$. Embarking on this, 1st count sequences with $m=1$. When finished, count those of $m=2$ and go on. So you have counted them all. For showing density, we must show that either any member of mother metric set say $X$ is a member of $P$ or is arbitrarily close to one such. In the latter case, take some non-periodic sequence $x \in X$. For any arbitrary $m$, there is a periodic sequence $p \in P$ with period $m$ whose its first $m$ bits are exactly the same as those of $x$. So by definition we conclude that $d(x,p)\le \frac{1}{m}$. Since $m$ is arbitrary this leads us to density.

2nd proof:

**Revision**

After $\sim 5$ years, I came back to check the answer and spotted some typos and ambiguities in the proof of compactness. Although the OP may so far have received well enough responses from the community, I will add up an update to my current answer, hopefully clarifying it to future readers.

1- We wish to prove that the space with the embedded metric is compact. In other words, we want to prove that any sequence of sequences $\left\{\left\{a_n^{(m)}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\right\}_{m=1}^\infty$ contains a subsequence $\left\{\left\{a_n^{(b_m)}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\right\}_{m=1}^\infty$, where $b_m:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ denotes the index of the subsequences. The proof continues by step-by-step construction of such a subsequence.

For any sequence $\left\{\left\{a_n^{(m)}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\right\}_{m=1}^\infty$, there are infinitely many $\left\{a_n^{(m)}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ either starting with $1$ or starting with $0$. We then refine $\left\{\left\{a_n^{(m)}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\right\}_{m=1}^\infty$ to keep only those sequences for which there are infinitely many sequences sharing the same value with $a_1^{(m)}$. To clarify the matter, if there were infinitely many $\left\{a_n^{(m)}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ starting with $1$, then remove the sequences starting with $0$ and vice versa. Name the new refined subsequences as $\left\{\left\{c_n^{(m)}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\right\}_{m=1}^\infty$. It is then clear that the maximal metric value over $\left\{\left\{c_n^{(m)}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\right\}_{m=1}^\infty$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Let us move on. This time, among the sequences of $\left\{\left\{c_n^{(m)}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\right\}_{m=1}^\infty$, we look for those sequences $\left\{c_n^{(m)}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with either $c_2^{(m)}=1$ or $c_2^{(m)}=0$ and for which there are infinitely many such sequences there. We refine this set into $\left\{\left\{d_n^{(m)}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\right\}_{m=1}^\infty$ through removing the other sequences. The maximal metric value in $\left\{\left\{d_n^{(m)}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\right\}_{m=1}^\infty$ would then be $\frac{1}{4}$. Continuing this process, we have finally built a subsequence of sequences converging to a fixed sequence.

Comment: $\{0,1\}^N$ refers to the set of infinite sequences of 0s and 1s. I thought this was clear (standard notation) but I edited the title to clarify this.

Comment: So what is $N$ standing for? I thought it refers to binary sequences of length $N$....

Comment: Thank you. I’m not quite following your proof for compactness. Which subsequence are you saying clearly converges?

Comment: There are infinitely many sequences started with say $1$ because of symmetry. Among those, there are infinitely many sequences started with say $11$. Next with $111$ and so on.

Comment: okay so in that case we would be constructing a subsequence that converges to $111111111...$?

Comment: Yes that's true but there might be subsequences converging to $1011010100.....$. What I mentioned is an example. You can arbitrarily replace any of ones with zero through symmetry.

Comment: Okay I think I am starting to understand better. I am still a bit confused conceptually about one thing: how will every subsequence will have an infinite number of sequences  starting with 0s and with 1s? It’s not obvious to me why this is the case.

Comment: Also, the original sequence has to be a non-constant sequence, correct? (Otherwise the result is trivial).

Comment: Yes we generally don't have such constraints....

Comment: Jane, you  might look up Konig's Lemma, which contains the basic idea behind the construction in part 1 -- it's about finite branching trees. In our case, you can view the space of sequences as the set of infinite paths through a binary branching tree, and our proof here shows that for any infinite set $S$ of (infinite) paths through the tree, there is at least one path $x$ for which $S$ contains elements that agree with $x$ arbitrarily far down the sequence..